# How to perform redirect to another page from custom JSP Component?

Tags: websphere-portal, lotus-wcm

I've got simple index.jsp file, ecluding imports looks like :

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://stackoverflow.com"); %>
```

I'm not redirected when I load page with this JSP Component.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use simple href if you want to navigate to google or so like sites, i.e. out of your application.

Comment: Hi,The problem was that the response is generated by WCM, therefore the header is already commited. Therefore all Redirects from server side won't work.  The only way to accomplish the results is to add javascript script, that redirects. ( ugly but works )

Comment: cool post your answer with some code, it may help others

Comment: if(some_condition) {%><script>window.location = "<%=redirectURL%>";</script><% }